# SQL comparing all values in a many-one table

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows

```
column1 column2
    a     1
    a     2
    b     2
```

I need to write an sql query that will go through the table and return me all column 2 values that have both a and b in column 1.

Comment: Many ways, self join, group by, exists etc.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to sql, so could you give an example?

Comment: Also known as `relational division`. There are different variants depending on e.g. should you return a value that has an `a`, `b` and `c` in column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT column2
FROM mytable
WHERE column1 IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY column2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column1) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY column1 Order by column1 )as rowCounts  into #tmp2
    FROM #tmp 

SELECT column2 FROM #tmp2 WHERE rowCounts = 1
```